# Chrome dev editor can't get packages, and can't run the basic app

Tags: google-chrome, web, dart, editor, chrome-dev-editor

I have installed a Chrome dev editor tool, created a dart web app, and I unable to run it I get this error when I try to run it [image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0bvdaa1rrdogwyi/Screenshot%202015-12-16%2010.50.50.png?dl=0)

Then I tried to get the packages "Pub Get" and get this error [image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l96dpxku8naijf8/Screenshot%202015-12-16%2010.56.04.png?dl=0)

I installed the dart via brew still the same.

Comment: Can you please add the images to the question. Links become stale easily which would render it useless for developers looking for a solution to the same problem.

Comment: How do you use CDE, on a Chromebook or a PC?

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer What do you mean to the question? I don't have enough reputation for showig images. I'm using it on Mac OS X

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't aware that this feature is limited by reputation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly causes your first error message but the 2nd is caused by an old Dart SDK version. Dart before about 1.8.0 isn't able to parse version constraints using the shorthand notation `^`

Comment: In the [chrome web store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-dev-editor-develop/pnoffddplpippgcfjdhbmhkofpnaalpg?hl=en) it says that it was last updated on 10th September 2015.

Comment: Chrome Dev Editor is no longer being actively developed (but this does not means that it is deprecated). Your information is not correct.